# Devise call backs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Does devise have call backs when a user signs in and out?

## This is what I came up with:

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
  user.update_attribute(:currently_signed_in, true)
end

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts|
  user.update_attribute(:currently_signed_in, false)
end
```

This is what I came with to track users that are currently signed in.

Comment: before_logout works fine, but after_authentication is not triggered when a user signs up, only when he signs in... It's not the normal behaviour, right? Any ideas?

Comment: Any idea on how to combine with token logins?

Comment: What do you mean by token logins?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm no expert but I believe the callbacks (hooks) are at the Warden level (Devise is built on top of Warden).

after_set_user and before_logout in Warden should do the trick for you but there are other options listed in [Warden::Hooks](http://rubydoc.info/github/hassox/warden/master/Warden/Hooks)

Comment: Sweet, I will try those and and get back to ya!

Comment: Hooks can go into `config/initializers/devise.rb` in case anyone was wondering like I was.

Comment: can you use methods from your application controller when you do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can overwrite sign_in in your application controller like this

```
 def sign_in(*args)
   super(*args)
    # do whatever you want here
    token = current_user.authentications.where(provider: "facebook").first.token
    facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
    session[:facebook] = facebook
end
```