# Update Attributes After Sign In Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise in a Rails 3 app.

I would like to update some attributes of a User on a successful sign in.

I am doing it the following way:

I added following code to application_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
   @user = current_user
   @user.status = "online"
   @user.save

   root_path
end
```

Is it possible to have a different method for doing this and not using the method that is used for defining the after_sign_in_path ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850057/devise-call-backs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850057/devise-call-backs)

Comment: Thanks eugen! It's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Eugen, can you "answer" this question by pointing to the URL?  That way this question will not show up in the unanswered questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with hooks to warden.

```
##config/initializers/devise.rb

Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
  user.update_attribute(:currently_signed_in, true)
end

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts|
  user.update_attribute(:currently_signed_in, false)
end
```