# How do i update a user attribute after signing in and signing out with devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am starting to use devise and i want to be able to update a user attribute to online or off line. i have this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    #update user status to online
    root_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    #update user status to offline
    root_path
  end
end
```

but i do not no how to write the update method

Comment: looks like you just need to add it to `create` and `destroy` actions in `SessionsController`

Comment: i get it. but what am i going to write under those actions i not so good at writing authentication codes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done this in the past:

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
  user.update_attribute(:currently_signed_in, true)
end

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts|
  user.update_attribute(:currently_signed_in, false)
end
```

See this question: [Devise call backs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850057/devise-call-backs)

Comment: Finding this was a headache for me :)