# strange Devise / Warden hooks error / behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I have implemented the code in [Devise call backs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850057/devise-call-backs) in my application controller. First of all is this the right place?

I get both the

```
after_authentication
```

and

```
after_set_user
```

to work. But I get this error for

```
before_logout

NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#destroy
undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass
```

The funny thing is that the database record is updated, dispite the error message. Strange.

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to do?

Comment: I have a user model and a userlogin model. When a user login I want to create a userlogin entry where I store, ip, session, datetime, agent, etc etc. When the user logout I want to update that record with logout time. The login and logout can be initiated from any page thats why I placed it in the application controller or shall I override the devise session and place the code there?

Comment: The trackable module built into devise already tracks login time, count, and ip address. As far as updating a dateline on logout, yes you would want to override the destroy method of the session controller of devise, there should be no need to go deeper into warden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a while back. When I implemented the after_authentication and before_logout I got multiple records, really strange.

To clarify I wanted to store ip etc on every session not just the last session.

I solved it by adding this in the config/initializers/devise.rb. Add code for what ever you want to store about the session.

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
  #store what ever you want on login
end

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts|
  # store what ever you want on logout
  # If not in initializer it will generate two records (strange)
end
```