# How to let the Application controller know that a user has signed in (users are handled with devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Devise to handle users in a shopping application. What I want to do is create a new cart each time a user signs in (and ideally, destroy the same cart each time a user signs out, but I'll just stick to that first part for this question).

So far, I've looked at this question: [Devise call backs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850057/devise-call-backs)

And I came up with this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :fetch_categories

  .
  .
  .

  Warden::Manager.after_authentication do
    session[:cart_id] ||= Cart.create!.id
  end
end
```

...But clearly this isn't correct, because I'm getting this error:

```
NameError in Devise::SessionsController#create

undefined local variable or method `session' for ApplicationController:Class
```

Is there some other way I can tell the application controller to respond to a user sign in, or should I be putting this code elsewhere (other than the application controller)? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glancing at [the docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/hassox/warden/master/Warden/Hooks#after_set_user-instance_method), it looks like you can do something like this:

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user, auth, opts|
  auth.session[:cart_id] ||= Cart.create!.id
end
```

Comment: This appears to have worked! One thing before I mark as the answer: do you have any idea why you have to call auth.session instead of just session?

Comment: Because `ApplicationController` doesn't have a class method called `session`. `session` is an instance method (and in your code you're calling it in the class context). My code works because `after_authentication` passes the authentication proxy object into the block as the second parameter (which I call `auth`), and that object has a `session` method that returns the authenticated user's session data.

Answer (score -1):

Simpally write a before filter

In `application controller`

`before_filter :set_current_user`

`def set_current_user
   Authorization.current_user = current_user
end`

and

you can check throughout application

using

```
 ` if !current_user.nil? 

  end`
```